# Dual Boot Windows 10, 4 partition maximum

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10. I shrunk my windows 10 partition to create space for Ubuntu but when I try to partition the free space I am told I can't make more than 4 partitions. I'm not sure what to do/if I can delete either one of those 2 450MB partitions?

[image: Partitions]

[image]

Comment: Like the error says, you need to create an extended partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/206788/creating-extended-partition

Comment: Well, who knows what's on those partitions? If you don't know, it's a problem, we obviously have no way to know.

Comment: @Zacharee1 how do I do that if I cant create a new partition? Wouldn't I have to delete one of the existing partitions?

Comment: Well like @mikewhatever said, we don't know what's on them. You have two diag partitions. Maybe check them out and see what's there?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I know that they're recovery partitions created by Windows 10, is there more info about them that might be useful?

Comment: Well it's really up to you if you want to delete them. You could always move the files off one, delete it, make an extended partition and then put them on an NTFS partition under the extended one.

Comment: @Zacharee1 that worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two recovery partitions. I don't know what's on them, and I don't know if it would be helpful to know what's on them. Because of that, I recommend the following setup.

Since the drive is MBR, you're limited to four primary partitions. If you want more, you need an extended partition, with logical partitions under it. Since you already have four partitions, you can't create the extended partition without deleting some other partitions.

Mount the two recovery partitions (`sda3` and `sda4`), and copy all the files off of them. Use Gparted to delete both of them and then set up your Ubuntu partition, leaving at least 1GB of free space after it. In this free space, create your extended partition and then recreate the two recovery partitions. Copy the respective files back in.

This way, you keep all your partitions and get Ubuntu. I don't know if the recovery partitions will work the way they're supposed to, but they're there if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older (non-UEFI) computer, its hard disk is probably formatted with a MBR partition table. The big limiting factor with this type of partition table is that it can only have 4 (maximum) partitions. Many people need more than 4, so what is done is to create 3 **primary** partitions, and one **extended** partition. The extended partition can contain more than 1 partition inside of it. Tricky way to get around the 4 partition limit, yes?

Most modern computers (UEFI) use the GPT partition tables, which allow the use of up to 128 individual partitions, eliminating the need for the extended partition trick. Also, most modern hard disk drives 2TB or larger also require the use of GPT partition tables.

So, to answer your specific question, the answer is no, don't delete any of your 4 existing partitions. You would probably loose the ability to run vendor diagnostics, or the ability to restore the OS in case of catastrophic failure.

If you post a screenshot of a **gparted** view of your sda drive, we can better answer on how to proceed.

update: I've looked at your gparted screenshot. And yes, sda3/4 are diag/restore partitions. If you don't mind loosing that capability, you could delete them. I'd also shrink your Windows partition **USING WINDOWS DISK MANAGEMENT APPLICATION**, not gparted, to make more room for Ubuntu.

Cheers, Al

Comment: The screenshots are linked ( I couldn't embed because I don't have 10 points yet)